# Converting string values to their metric equivalents in actionscript?

Tags: regex, string, actionscript-3, metric

Can anyone suggest the best approach for metric conversion of string values?
for instance distance values,and temperatures

For instance say I have a string containing some unknown inches value

And the inches sign can either be the proper double prime OR double quotes.

So, I'm guessing as a first step I would search for double prime or double quotes preceded by a number value, then parse out and convert this number value.
But this doesn't seem foolproof for instances when it is actually a doublequote, NOT an inches sign

Answer (score 0):

You can split your input string like this:

`split('"')`

or this:

`split("''")`

Then pass the results of the returned array to `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`.